# AsyncTCP C# - arduino/unity communication

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working the last weeks with a tcp protocol to send packet from arduino to unity using this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class TCPConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string IP_Seat = "192.168.137.161";  
    public int port = 34197;
    #region private members     
    private TcpClient socketConnection;
    private Thread clientReceiveThread;
    public float a, b, c, vel;
    public float test = 0.0f;
    #endregion
    // Use this for initialization  
    void Awake()
    {
        ConnectToTcpServer();
    }
    
    /// <summary>   
    /// Setup socket connection.    
    /// </summary>  
    private void ConnectToTcpServer()
    {
        try
        {
            clientReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForData));
            clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
            clientReceiveThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background clientReceiveThread; Listens for incoming data.  
    /// </summary>     
    private void ListenForData()
    {
        var aold = 0.0f;
        var bold = 0.0f;
        var cold = 0.0f;
        var velold = 0.0f;
        try
        {
            socketConnection = new TcpClient(IP_Seat, port);
            //cketConnection.ConnectAsync(IP_Seat, port);  // non si connette
            //socketConnection.Client.Blocking = false;
            //socketConnection.Client.ConnectAsync(IP_Seat,port);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[16];
            while (socketConnection.Connected)
            {
                // Get a stream object for reading              
                using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;
                    // Read incoming stream into byte arrary.                   
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        //Debug.Log("I'm receiving Data");
                        if (length == 16)
                        {
                            //Debug.Log("I'm receiving len 16 and I like it");
                            var incomingData = new byte[length];
                            var A = new Byte[4];
                            var B = new Byte[4];
                            var C = new Byte[4];
                            var VEL = new Byte[4];

                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);
                            // Convert byte array to string message.                        
                            string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);
                             Array.Copy(bytes, 0, A, 0, 4);
                             Array.Copy(bytes, 4, B, 0, 4);
                             Array.Copy(bytes, 8, C, 0, 4);
                             Array.Copy(bytes, 12, VEL, 0, 4);



                            a = BitConverter.ToSingle(A, 0) < 0 ? BitConverter.ToSingle(A, 0) : aold;
                            b = BitConverter.ToSingle(B, 0) < 0 ? BitConverter.ToSingle(B, 0) : bold;
                            c = BitConverter.ToSingle(C, 0) < 0 ? BitConverter.ToSingle(C, 0) : cold;
                            vel = BitConverter.ToSingle(VEL, 0); //< 0 ? BitConverter.ToSingle(C, 0) : 0;

                            //Debug.Log("server message received as: " + serverMessage +a +" "+b + " " + c + " " + vel);

                            aold = a;
                            bold = b;
                            cold = c;
                            velold = vel;

                        }
                        else {
                            //evitare che bilancia aspetti ack di tcp
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
        }
    }

}
```

and right now i'm having blocking issues: i'd like to use the async method for the TCP but the `tcpClient.ConnectAsync`  but it returns a SocketEXception and I can't figure out why.

The arduino sends 4 float in 16 bytes packet and 98-99% of them arrive correctly, but the missing 1-2% causes the system to block and an undesirable behaviour ( since i'm programming a device I need no delay waiting for an ack or a packet)

How can I make this sokcet async?

EDIT:
Using NET 4.X: how can I use the connectASync(ip,port) method in this script?

Comment: Problem is following : length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0.  You need a termination for each message.  Either fixed length, terminate with character that is not part of data, or add a byte count to beginning of message.  TCP you gets split during transmission based on timers and what you send in one message can be split into multiple receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

As already said TCP is just an undefined stream of data you need to implement an according protocol for knowing when a message ends (is fully received) and when a new one starts.

Now in your case you seem to already know that you have exactly `16` bytes.

[`NetworkStream.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read#system-net-sockets-networkstream-read(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)) however, does not necessarily wait until actually `16` bytes where received. If for some reason (delay in the network) at the moment it is called there are less bytes in the stream then it will receive only the amount that is available.

Now let's say your sender sends 3 packages á 16 bytes (so 48 bytes).

It might happen that the first time you read only 8 bytes. From now on every following read call receives 16 bytes.
=> **Result**: You get two complete buffers, **but** with invalid data since you always started reading at the middle of a message.

Note the second parameter of `Read`

```
int offset -> The location in buffer to begin storing the data to.
```

what you want to do is wait until the buffer is actually full like

```
var receivedBytes = 0;
while (receivedBytes < bytes.Length)
{
    receivedBytes +=  stream.Read(bytes, receivedBytes, bytes.Length - receivedBytes);
}

// Use bytes
```

Now this will fill exactly one buffer of `16` bytes before continuing since at the same time we increase the offset we also decrease the maximum amount of bytes to read.

---

And another note: you have a huge amount of redundant array creations, copies and `BitConverter` going on!

I would rather use

```
var bytes = new byte[16];
var floats = new float[4];
```

And then later on after receiving the bytes do

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, floats, 0, 16);
```

This copies the bytes over into floats directly in the underlaying byte layer.

And then you can simply do

```
a = floats[0] < 0 ? floats[0] : aold;
b = floats[1] < 0 ? floats[1] : bold;
c = floats[2] < 0 ? floats[2] : cold;
v = floats[3];
```

---

*Note: Typed on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: That helped a lot, but still the lost packet rate persist. I updated other parts of the project to use NET 4.X: can I use the connectAsync method?

Comment: @L.Vezzani sure you can .. but that won't make any difference regarding the receiving process .. you se to already have a working connection anyway so why do you want to change to `ConnectAsync` ?

Comment: because the sync method is blocking and it causes delays. also I believe the arduino doesn't exit the writing process until it receives an ack.

Comment: @L.Vezzani Yes and it makes sense that the connect call is blocking since you don't want to execute the rest of your code until you actually are connected. The TCP protocol in general works with Ack packages, that's nothing you have to worry about. As soon as you are connected you start reading the stream in exactly the order it has been written by the server side

Comment: @L.Vezzani from your code it is unfortunately unclear how you are going to use these received values .. what exactly makes you think that they are not all received?

Comment: I use these data to control objects in the scene (transform and rotation): once in a while both the arduino and the data stream blocks: the arduino blocks at the client.write(floats) line and the tcp doesn't receive any new data. the block might last even 1 second, and thats something the application cannot tolerate. I thought that sending async packet might eliminate this behaviour and allow the arduino to write freely

Comment: @L.Vezzani your TCP stuff already runs async since it is in a Thread -> This doesn't "block". What might happen though is that you spam the network with so much data that it isn't reading fast enough .. another possibility: Some network devices (routers / network cards) use a buffer and don't immediately forward all packages. You might want to go for UDP if it isn't totally necessary to receive all packages in exactly the correct order but you rather only need a "current value" snapshot anyway

Comment: I tried converting this script to a UDP one, but I wasn't able to